# django do not save thumbnails from imagekit

Tags: python, django

```
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='home/', blank=True)
    thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='image', processors=[ResizeToFill(50, 50)],format='JPEG', options={'quality':60})
```

when I uploading image. Everything OK with original image. But there is no thumbnail image.
I guess this problem is related with cache. Maybe I am wrong. Can't figure out what to do... 
Please help.

Comment: What's happening when using `image.thumbnail.url`?

Comment: I guess it will work fine when I use image.thumbnail.url Issue not in that. The issue is that django do not save thumbnail image. it must be somewhere in the project STORED. right? But it doesn't! And I can't figure out how to solve  this problem.

Comment: OK, as specified in docs, by default, Image kit defer thumbs creation until content is required.

https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/caching.html?highlight=caching#cache-file-strategy

Comment: @Julien Kieffer, can I change this default behaviour and just save thumbnail right after original image uploaded? And thank you for reply, help, attention!

Comment: Julien Kieffer, can you put your comment text to the answer section? I would like to check it as best answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to "enforce" file generation, your 'IMAGEKIT_DEFAULT_CACHEFILE_STRATEGY`should implement`on_source_saved`.

One is provided but the package, and adding:

```py
IMAGEKIT_DEFAULT_CACHEFILE_STRATEGY = 'imagekit.cachefiles.strategies.Optimistic'
```

to your `settings.py` will enforce file generation on source save.

Now please pay attention: this will "only" work when using `ImageSpecField` and you might have an hard time using this strategy with `templatetags` or `ImageSpec` without handling correctly [source groups](https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#source-groups)

Another way is to write your custom ``` CACHEFILE_STRATEGY``
In ```some_app/strategy.py`

```py
class CustomStrategy(object):
    """
    A strategy that ensures file creation on save and existence

    """

    def on_existence_required(self, file):
        file.generate()

    def on_content_required(self, file):
        file.generate()

    def on_source_saved(self, file):
        file.generate()
```

Now, adding

```py
IMAGEKIT_DEFAULT_CACHEFILE_STRATEGY = 'your_app.strategy.CustomStrategy'
```

to your `settings.py` should work like a charm.

Comment: Wov! it is something amazing! Thank you very much! it does exactly what I wanted. You are my hero!